# Open a fragment from a fragment's fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment with a ListView. When I click one of the item, a new Fragment is opened, and from this Fragment I want to open a new Fragment witha a Button.
I try to write the code, but it's a mess. When a click the Button, the program is crashed.
Should I use another way? I call the third Fragment like the second

Activity:

```
 public class Grade extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceSt

ate);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.lista_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_list,
                    new Objectlist()).commit();
        }
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_tantargylista:
                            selectedFragment = new Objectlist();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_dolgozatlista:
                            selectedFragment = new Examlist();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_list,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

1st Fragment:

```
public class Objectlist  extends Fragment {

    View v;
    DB mydb;
    ListView listView;
    private String teszt;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_objectlist, container, false);

        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.Gradeview);
        mydb = new DB(getActivity());

        final ArrayList<String> thelist = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = mydb.getTantargynev();

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nincs jegyek hozzáadva", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                thelist.add(data.getString(0));
                ListAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, thelist);
                listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
            }


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                            teszt = thelist.get(i);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                            String jegyAtlag="0";
                            Cursor data = mydb.JegyekAtlaga(teszt);
                            while (data.moveToNext()) jegyAtlag=data.getString(0);

                            String jegyDarab="0";
                            data = mydb.JegyekDarabszama(teszt);
                            while (data.moveToNext()) jegyDarab=data.getString(0);

                            if (jegyAtlag.equals("") || jegyDarab.equals(""))

                            else {
                                bundle.putString("Tantárgy átlaga", jegyAtlag);
                                bundle.putString("Tantárgy darabszáma", jegyDarab);

                                TextView jegyekHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
                                jegyekHeader.setText(teszt);

                                Fragment targyAdatok = new targyAdatok();

                                Fragment jegyekAllando = new jegyekAllando();
                                jegyekAllando.setArguments(bundle);
                                FragmentTransaction FragTan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                FragTan.replace(R.id.jegyekMenu, targyAdatok);
                                ListView listaNezet = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.Gradeview);
                                listaNezet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                FragTan.commit();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

2nd Fragment:

public class targyAdatok extends Fragment {

```
public targyAdatok() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_targy_adatok, container, false);

    Button elemzes = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.elemzes);
    elemzes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment jegyekAllando = new jegyekAllando();
            FragmentTransaction FragTan = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragTan.replace(R.id.targyAdatok,jegyekAllando);
            FragTan.commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

3rd Fragment:

```
    public class jegyekAllando extends Fragment {

        DB mydb;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jegyek_allando, container, false);

Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        String jegyAtlagSt = bundle.getString("Tantárgy átlaga");
        String jegyDarabSt = bundle.getString("Tantárgy darabszáma");

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code that you wrote that's crashing the app. Hard to speculate without seeing the code.

Comment: Okay, I uploaded it. Sorry, in the program I use another language.

Comment: You have to post your crash log.


But in terms of your fragment navigation, it's messy.  It shouldn't structure this way.  It's better if you draw a diagram to describe what page to what page and which portion of screen is for which fragment.

You should either handle all fragment transaction in one place (Your activity) by building callbacks to activity and listeners.  Or use getChildFragmentManager for nested fragments transactions.  But it's hard to tell without diagrams.

Comment: I will upload the crash log, as soon as possible. But how can I handle the fragments from Activity? I don't know the syntacs.

Comment: Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem was that a replaced the wrong fragment. Every time I have to replace the Activity's Fragment.